# Data not saved for managed object context core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a managed object context defined in my app delegate (Apple boiler plate code).

I'm trying to have a save triggered when a secondary window closes and have this code:

```
NSLog(@"close and save");
HEFTAppDelegate *appDelegate = (HEFTAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext commitEditing]) {
    NSLog(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
}
```

This doesn't seem to result in data being saved.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the error message that gets displayed at the end?

Comment: I dont get any error messages

Comment: How did you deduce that data is not being saved?

Comment: No persistance on restarting app. I've linked a push button to the save action method on the app delegate and this saves the data fine